# Copy and paste from Excel to MVC3

Tags: excel, asp.net-mvc-3

We need to be able to copy a few hundred rows at a time from Excel into a MVC3 web app.

Problem: is there a better way to do this?

- giant text box to paste into, then string split in the controller
- ExtJs Grid drag n drop http://www.vinylfox.com/datadrop-drag-grid-data-from-spreadsheet/
- linq to excel - http://code.google.com/p/linqtoexcel/

[image]

Comment: Linq to Excel probably won't help you with pasting it into a webpage.  Would help if you wanted to upload it to the server and do stuff to it though.

Comment: @R0manarmy agreed.. would give some nice safety as it looks at column headers..